# internal server eroor 500 django when using simplejson.loads(request.raw_post_data)

Tags: jquery, django, json, internal-server-error

I'm trying to receive a json object from my jquery client but when I call the simplejson.loads(request.raw_post_data) I get internal server error 500. The server receives the call since I'm getting the callback fro the server when the simplejson.loads(request.raw_post_data) line is commented. But as soon as I uncomment that line the error is thrown.

ajaxtest.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#post").click(function(){
            var test = new Object();
            test.name = "Kalle";
            test.pw = "kula";
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajaxtest/",
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {client_response: JSON.stringify(test), csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{  csrf_token}}'},
                success: function(result) {
                    alert(result);
                } 
            });
        });      
    });
</script>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils import simplejson
from manges.models import User

# Create your views here.

def ajax_test(request):
print 'Hej'
if request.method == 'GET':
    print 'GET'
    c = User.objects.get(pk=1)
    print c.emailadress
    print c.password
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(c, default=User.serializable))
if request.method == 'POST':
    print 'POST'
    data = simplejson.load(request.raw_post_data)
    print json_data.name
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps('Got JSON!'))      

def start_page(request):
print 'Start'
return render_to_response('ajaxtest.html',      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from manges.views import ajax_test, start_page
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('manges.views',
url(r'^$', start_page),
url(r'^ajaxtest/$', ajax_test),
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'myforum.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  
)
```

Any ideas??

Comment: Please turn on DEBUG = True and add a full error stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

raw_post_data doesn't contain JSON, which is why the conversion is throwing.

When you send the request, you passed this data

```
{client_response: JSON.stringify(test), csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{  csrf_token}}'}
```

Jquery serializes that object in POST parameters. See the page for [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

So on the server side, HttpRequest.raw_post_data doesn't have JSON directly. To extract the JSON, you need to use the POST parameter that contains JSON, accessible through

```
request.POST["client_response"]
```