# Using JSON data in Django view

Tags: jquery, django, json, pythonanywhere

I'm setting up a rating system and am struggling to utilize JSON data into my Django view. The end goal will be to save a rating into my BlogSiteRating model:

```
#models.py
class BlogSiteReview(models.Model):
  blog_site = models.ForeignKey(BlogSite)
  review_rating = models.IntegerField()
```

However, I'm not quite to that point yet. I was having 403 errors, but those have been resolved by using the csrf token correctly in the POST. Now I am getting a 500 error passed back from the server, which can be seen in the chrome console.

EDIT: Found the error finally. There are 2 POSTs being performed. Both give a MultiValueDictKeyError error

The first says: Key 'rating' not found in "< QueryDict: {u'rating[rating]': [u'10'], u'rating[csrfmiddlewaretoken]': [u'0468d70cfb6fc425a530d434f5a4c30a'], u'rating[rateid]': [u'7']}>

The second says: "Key 'rating' not found in "< QueryDict: {u'action': [u'rating'], u'rate': [u'10'], u'idBox': [u'7']}>"

Here is the JSON I am passing to my view.

```
//JSON object being passed into views.py
$(".rating").jRating({
      onSuccess : function(element,rate){
          var rating = [
            { "id":element.id.replace('rating', ''), "rating":rate}
          ];

          rating["csrfmiddlewaretoken"] = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();

          alert("Passed id:" + element.id.replace('rating', '') + " and rating:" + rate);

          //send post data to django view
          $.post('/blogsearch/setrating/', {"rating":rating}, function(msg)
            {
                if(msg.error == "yes")
                {console.log('Error Found: '+ msg.errorMsg);}
            }, 'json');
      },
      onError : function(){
        alert('Error : please retry again later, the server did not accept your submission.');
      }
    });
```

And finally, here is what I have in my views.py:

```
#views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils import simplejson

def setrating(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            simplejson.loads(request.POST['rating'])
            #data = 1 #Note: when I uncomment this line, and 
                      #comment the above line, I don't get a 500 error
    return HttpResponse("success")
```

Also, I know I am not attempting to save anything in my model in this example. If I can get the JSON data in my view, I should be able to save it from there without problems. But, if you would like you could help with that code in the answer.

---

I've been looking at posts for a few days now, and some of the ones that have led me down this path are:

[internal server eroor 500 django when using simplejson.loads(request.raw_post_data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442759/internal-server-eroor-500-django-when-using-simplejson-loadsrequest-raw-post-da)

[Getting internal server error when trying to handle json in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564179/getting-internal-server-error-when-trying-to-handle-json-in-django)

I have also tried with importing json instead of simplejson, and I get the same result.
I have played around with using request.raw_post_data as well, but I get the server error with that method. From what I've read it looks like request.POST['rating'] is the right thing to use?

Comment: What error message do you get? You can use for example Chrome's inspector tool to see the response. It should give you some directions about the error that is occurring.

Comment: Also inspect the data you are posting. Is it JSON-encoded, or plain formdata encoding?

Comment: Found the error finally. It is "Key 'rating' not found in <QueryDict: {u'action': [u'rating'], u'rate': [u'9'], u'idBox': [u'7']}>" and the CONTENT_TYPE is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' Looks like it's returning unicode objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - There were 2 problems.

First, in the JS, I noticed there were 2 POSTs being performed. I actually didn't need to write any of the JS, the JRating was performing the POST on its own, and sending it to a variable I set in the settings of the plug-in.

The other problem (the more important one) was in the views.py. I was expecting a variable called 'rating', because that is what I was setting in my JS. In reality, I needed to grab each variable separately, and one of the POST calls wasn't even using the rating variable.

```
def setrating(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            rating = json.loads(request.POST['rate'])
            id = json.loads(request.POST['idBox'])
    return HttpResponse("the rating for " + str(id) + " is " + str(rating))
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest several things that can at least help us figure out what the problem is:

1. set **DEBUG = True** in your settings so you can get the whole traceback in the result and not just the 500.
2. Post us the answer you get in the view: **print request['POST']**
3. use a ModelForm based on your model and use Django built-in form validation to help you handle the data.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have the DEBUG set to True, but it is not showing me the error page - I think maybe because it is an AJAX request? I'm seeing the 500 error returned in the console log of Chrome.

I've been trying to see the data through print, but haven't been able to see anything. When I add in that line it errors out and I can't see anything. I also do not see anything in the linux error log :( Do you have any suggestions of how to get around that so we can see the error, or possibly another place to look?

#3 makes sense and I will be doing that after I can see the data in the view.

Comment: you should be able to view the details of the 500 response in the chrome debug console -- click on the ajax error, and see if you can view the response...

Comment: Ok, I have some answers now. The error message I get back is "Exception Type: TypeError at /blogsearch/setrating/Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute '__getitem__'" I get this error message when I print request['POST'], but I can see that the post data contains action u'rating' rate u'11'
idBox 
u'7'